# How to suppress warning for mkfs

Tags: linux, shell

when doing mkfs on a whole disk instead of a partition, it will issue a warning like
"this is not a partition! do you want to proceed?"
And you have to manually type "y" to proceed.

Can I suppress this warning and make mkfs just go through without asking me?

Comment: man-pages for the world!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `-F` option:

> Force mke2fs to create a filesystem, even if the specified device is
>   not  a  partition on  a  block  special  device,  or if other
>   parameters do not make sense.